# Crystal Reports-Joining tables if exists

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, join, crystal-reports-2011

i have a problem, i have 4 tables that i require to join, i already did the join for 3 of them (lets call them table1, table2, table3), join until this point is working fine, the problem comes with the last table, here i need to ask if a record exist on table number 4 (which is a combination between foreign key 'the same used to join the other 3 tables plus one additional column value, which is not recorded for all records), then if record exists on table 4, i need to display its content 'one specific column from table4', otherwise just display it in blank. Has someone done this before?

This is the query with the first 3 tables join.

```
SELECT
TABLE1.NUMPROD as BATCH_ID,
TABLE2.EQPCODE as Tank,
TABLE1.CODEPROD as Product_Code,
TABLE1.XFIELD_03 as Sequence,
TABLE3.ITEM_CONSUMED as ITEM,
TABLE3.CONSUMPTION_QUANTITY as QUANTITY

FROM 
TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 on TABLE1.NUMPROD = TABLE3.ORDERID
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE3.ORDERID = TABLE2.NUMBERLOT

AND TABLE1.ETAT = 'F' 
AND TABLE1.DATECREATION BETWEEN ('20191001') AND ('20191004') 
AND TABLE1.XFIELD_03 IS NOT NULL
AND TABLE3.CONSUMPTION_QUANTITY > 0 
and TABLE2.VALUE = 'ASSIGNED'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT
TABLE1.NUMPROD as BATCH_ID,
...
TABLE3.CONSUMPTION_QUANTITY as QUANTITY,
--                                           --> from this line ...
(select some_column 
 from table4 t4
 where t4.some_id = table1.some_other_Id
) table_4_column                      
--                                           --> ... to this line
FROM 
TABLE1 JOIN ...
```

Query that fetches data from `table4` **must** return at most one value; otherwise, you'll get `too-many-rows` error.

Comment: The case i have is that table 4 contains only one record per entity, which is the record i need to display/retrieve, the problem is that not all entities have this record, then i need to display a list containing all info i already have from the others tables plus the record from table4 when it applies.

Comment: Well, that's how I understood the question. I re-read what you initially wrote and - to me - it still makes sense. If it doesn't do what you need, it would help if you posted test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data) and result you'd want to get out of such an input.